# vertical-align:middle not working

Tags: css

The text is supposed to sit in the middle (vertically) on the navigation bar.

My code isn't working.

Can anyone explain why?

```
<style>
#navigationbar { 
background: rgb(252,219,121);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%, rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(2%,rgba(252,219,121,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(254,191,1,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcdb79', endColorstr='#febf01',GradientType=0 );
height: 40px;
}

#logo {
color:white;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-left:10px;
}

* { 
margin:0px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<div id='navigationbar'>
    <a id='logo' href='http://localhost/'>WORK.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`vertical-align` only works on elements with specific properties, generally with the CSS table `display` properties (`table-cell`, `table`, `table-row` and so forth).

However there is a simple way to vertically center things when you know the height of their container.  Just add `line-height: 40px` to your `#logo` CSS (you could alternatively add it to the container, it makes no difference in this case).

```
#logo {
    color:white;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

If you wanted to use `vertical-align`, you would need to set `display: table` on the container (`#navigationbar`) and `display: table-cell` to your `#logo` that has `vertical-align: middle`.  This will achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the line height on the container for the vertical align to know what to be in the vertical middle of. See [JSBIN demo](http://jsbin.com/UKonOYe/1/)

```
#navigationbar { 
background: rgb(252,219,121);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%, rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(2%,rgba(252,219,121,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(254,191,1,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(252,219,121,1) 2%,rgba(254,191,1,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcdb79', endColorstr='#febf01',GradientType=0 );
height: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your current CSS ([demo here](http://jsbin.com/aLOpOJI/1/)):

```
#navigationbar {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#logo {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Like @[**Ennui**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600854/ennui) said:

> `vertical-align` only works on elements with specific properties, generally with the CSS table display properties (`table-cell`, `table`, `table-row` and so forth).

Answer (score 1):

You could use line-height:33px; , but i also recommend wrapping your 'a tag' into a 'div tag' , so it will be easy to manipulate it later on. Example:

```
<style>
#logo {
width: 30px;
height: 40px;   
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#logo a{
color: white;
line-height: 33px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id='navigationbar'>
    <div id='logo'><a href='http://localhost/'>WORK.</a></div>
</div>
</body>
```

If you need  to move that logo around later, it will be easy to just use absolute value on the #logo.